# How to configure git in ec2 with my local machine?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have installed git in ec2 instance and in my local machine.
I have used below commands in ec2 after installing git.

```
cd home/username/git
mkdir newproject.git
cd newproject.git
git init --bare

cd /var/www/html/projectname
git init
git add --all
git commit -m ”first commit”

git remote add origin username@181.177.2.11(ec2):/home/username/newproject.git
```

Below are the commands i executed after installing git.

```
Cd /var/www/html/projectname
git init
git add --all
git commit -m ”first commit”
git remote add origin username@181.177.2.11(EC2):/home/username/newproject.git
```

Now when i give the below command from my local machine

```
 git pull origin master
```

i am getting below error.

```
    Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

And then from my local machine when i give

```
git push origin master
```

i am getting below error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-181.177.2.11(EC2) Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

note: i usually login to ec2 through ssh by using a key.pem file.
someone  guide me how to configure git from local to ec2 machine?

Comment: Is this question about github or about setting git on your server?

Answer (score 4):

Using a key file with SSH is done with the `-i` option, but you can't use it with git.

The solution is to configure SSH to use this key. Set in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host THE_EC2_HOSTNAME_OR_IP
    IdentityFile /path/to/your/key.pem
```

Then when using a remote `username@THE_EC2_HOSTNAME_OR_IP:/path/to/repo.git`, it will automatically use the `key.pem` for authentication.

But be sure to use the EC2 instance IP or public DNS (your hostname is a little bit weird with parenthesis `181.177.2.11(EC2)`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the config file for the ssh server and restart the server.

alter /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

then restart the ssh server:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Comment: That is almost never a good idea to open pasword authentication to the world. Rather set up properly public key authentication.

Answer (score -1):

as said by @saravanan..
have a password authentication so that you can have a secured file transfers.
go to your sshd_config file and change password authentication to yes.
then restart your ssh server.then create a new bare and try it..
to create a new password

```
sudo passwd username
```

this will create a new password so that you can use this instead of .pem file..This is not the only way but it will work
Try it..

Answer (score -2):

First, create an account on GitHub

1. Just you need to first install gitHub. If Windows download exe and if Ubuntu than you need to run

   ```
   apt-get install git
   ```

The above command will set up git env in your local Machine

2. You need to configure git user

   ```
   git config --global user.name "Mayank Dwivedi"
   git config --global user.email "mayank@example.com"
   ```

Replace name with your git name and email id.